# MeanIO's swig template engine does not render the angular ng-model data

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack, swig-template

I use the meanIO's recommended module 'swig' for template engine. But I could not be suceessful in getting angular basic data binding.

Below setting in express server on NodeJS Platform :

```
 app.engine('html', consolidate[config.templateEngine]);
 app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.get('/', function(req,res){
    var values = {
        appName : config.appname
    }

    res.render('page1');
    //res.redirect('/login');
});
```

The above setting doesnt render the actual angular model on filling the textbox.

### index.Html

```
 <div>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
  <hr>
  <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
```

Where as the below settings works very fine to me .

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); // to render html files in response
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

What is the problem with swig module not rendering the ng-model data inside {{}} ???

Answer (score 8):

Change the default `varControls` in Swig to not be the exact same thing that Angular uses. They are colliding. http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/api/#SwigOpts

```
var swig = require('swig'); 
swig.setDefaults({ varControls: ['<%=', '%>'] }); // or anything besides ['{{', '}}']
```

Answer (score 0):

I never tried swig myself, but what you need is an alternative to Django's **verbatim** tag in swig, which ignores any `{{ }}` or `{% %}` in the template and letting angularjs do the work on the client side. By this [closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/issues/348) of swig project, you should wrap your angularjs block in the template with `{% raw %}`.

I couldn't find more detailed documentation but I hope it gives you a general direction of what you need in order to prevent collisions between swig's syntax and angularjs' syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you can also modify the default render behaviour of angular app as by including following script block

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function ($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]');
        });
    </script>
```